# How can I update a SQLite record's attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

I'm trying to update a `SQLite` record's `boolean` "Large" attribute in my code-behind. I'm using the `sqlite-net-pcl` Nuget package in `Xamarin.Forms` shared project.

I've figured out how to pass my record through to my method, but I can't get the attribute to update.

```
public async void PutBack(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedListItem = e.Item as ListItem;
    selectedListItem.Large = false
    ...
}
```

When I run this I don't get any errors, but nothing happens. What's the correct syntax to update a record? It's weirdly hard to find documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you had create `dependency` in platform. So just open connection to `SQLite` according to your path. Like what you had to do when query it back. Like this,

```
var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();   
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(platform, path);
```

then use that `conn` to run an update on that object after you edit.

```
conn.Update(selectedListItem);
```